# How to log output of a method into log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I log the stdout of a method to the corresponding log file.

The method which I want to log is called from another method in a model class. The function call looks like:

```
UpdateCount.new(@skus.to_s, @qty.to_s, @parent.to_s)
```

I tried using:

```
log(UpdateCount.new(@skus.to_s, @qty.to_s, @parent.to_s))
```

But this prints the following to the log file:

```
[2014-05-07 15:54:17] [Info] #<UpdateCount:0x12078318>
```

How can I use log(), or something else to print the stdout of this method to the log file.

Comment: Are you able to edit the method? If it is actually printing to stdout (i.e. using `puts` or similar) then it's going to be difficult to redirect that.

Comment: Yes, I am using something like puts. Actually the method triggers a python script, where I am using `print` statements

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at Logger. Simple documentation can be found here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger.